# VMWare - Import Amazon EC2 AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-web-services, vmware

I've seen lots of post regarding the opposite direction, e.g. porting a VMWare image to an AMI, but none about what I'm trying to do.  I have an AMI - the Amazon Linux AMI [Beta] - and I'd like to do some testing on a duplicate VM box before I make modifications to the current running one; anybody done this?

Answer (score 2):

Not *yet*. Currently, Amazon only supports VMWare *import*, and even then it's only for Windows 2008 Enterprise Server.

They've made statements, however, saying that they're currently working on support for not only exporting AMIs, but also supporting a wide variety of Linux distributions as well.

It's just not here yet. :( I'm looking forward to that feature as well.