# EC2 AMI snapshot

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there a way to play an EC2 AMI snapshot locally on a laptop?  For example, export the AMI snapshot to VMWare?  We have a sales team that need this ability when on the road with no internet connectivity (we currently use VMWare player for this).  Thanks.

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145286/boot-ec2-ebs-volume-locally

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is still not possible for an AMI to be exported direct to VMware: 
[VMWare - Import Amazon EC2 AMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908641/vmware-import-amazon-ec2-ami/4982153#4982153)

However, it is possible to mount the EBS that contains the AMI of interest to a fresh, running instance and then use VMware tools to image it and distribute that to your mobile people: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/188775